# How do you provide builds for clients, when they do not want to give you access to their developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a client that has their own enterprise distribution account. They do not want to give me access to their account for security reasons, I don't want to give them unsigned source code for obvious reasons.

What is the best way to handle this situation to create sample builds for them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe off topic: but you can create a static lib from your code, create a new App with the lib and send the Xcode Project to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on the Apple Developer Website and I think I have found the answer to my question

**I am a contractor who wants to create an in-house app for my client. Can I join the iOS Developer Enterprise Program to do that?**

*No. The iOS Developer Enterprise Program is for companies/organizations to develop and distribute proprietary in-house apps to their employees.
Your client should enroll in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program and add the appropriate developers from your company to their iOS Development Team.*

From reading that It sounds like I need to have them add me as a developer on the team which will give me some limited access.

Answer (score 1):

A service like  [testflight](http://www.testflightapp.com) would be my starting point.

You build an adhoc build, register their devices, and distribute it to them to test it.

You don't need their Distribution profiles, and they don't need your code.  Everyone's fairly happy!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I plan on using test flight but we are a small development company, and need our "100" registered devices. They have their devices already provisioned... So I still need to be able to use their "adhoc" provisioning profile

Comment: are you using all 100 right now?  You can always add their devices then remove them later when the project is done.  Or, create a new developer account and charge it to the client?

Comment: Hi Kaos- That is not correct, once you add a device to your development account, it is there for an entire year (even if you remove the device, the "spot" is held until your account renews)

Answer (score 0):

You could add their testing device(s) to your own adhoc profile and distribute the app with your adhoc-certificate.